# how to create common adapter class for all recycler view android

Tags: listview, android-recyclerview

I have to create the separate adapter  class for all the Recyclerview .any way to achieve the single adapter class for all the Recycler view?

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        System.out.println("$$$bind");

        if(fragmentName.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            holder.text.setText("");
            holder.text.setBackgroundResource();
            holder.textValue.setBackgroundResource();
            holder.textValue.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.coupons_arrow, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        if(fragmentName.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            holder.text.setText("name");
            holder.text.setBackgroundResource(R.color.c_101035);
            holder.textValue.setBackgroundResource(R.color.c_7b7bff);
            holder.textValue.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.deals_arrow_img, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        if (fragmentName.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                holder.text.setText("");
                holder.text.setBackgroundResource(R.color.c_10331);
                holder.textValue.setBackgroundResource(R.color.c_alpha_7dfff2);
                holder.textValue.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.visiting_offer_arrow, 0, 0, 0);
            }
          //Model obj= new FragmentTodaytip();
          //obj.getTitle();
       // holder.servicename.setText("ccheckkk");

    }
```

This how created.it makes large number of view to be include in bind and view holder for each recycler listitems any alternate way to acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the same adapter, you just need to do some extra coding in ur adapter.

Create two different constructors for two different RecyclerViews.

Let's say one Recycler View contains 1 textView, so you need to pass one String only, for RecyclerView containing 2 textViews, pass two strings.

For example if the Adapter class is **MyAdapter** use the following constructor.

```
 public MyAdapter(String[] myDataset,String[] mySecondaryDataset, Context context) {
    mDataset = myDataset;
    mSecondaryDataset=mySecondaryDataset;
    this.context=context;

}

public MyAdapter(String[] myDataset,Context context)
{
    mDataset=myDataset;
    this.context=context;
}
```

and make such changes in ur Adapter code wherever u need.